# CSV file transform in a value x

Tags: python, csv

I am quite new in programming in Phyton.
I want to open a CSV file, that contains differents numbers, like on line 1 and column 1 (cell 1), cell 2, many numbers.
I then want to extract that numbers for each cell and give a value of x to cell 1, then y to cell 2, and so on. Note that on the CSV file there is only number written, no x, y, z...
The CSV file will vary, that are medical datas that vary a lot, therefore I need to open the CSV file and not writing directly on the code.
Then once I can attribute the value of x to a number, I can then run my program and display some outputs (using conditional programmin for example).
Does someone knows so how I can open a CSV file and attribute the value of a cell to a x variable ?

Comment: Check [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: The approach of assigning one cell at a time to x, y, z will not work for anything beyond very tiny and simple datasets. Instead, use `pandas` or R for most convenient manipulation of tabular data from a CSV. Check out the [pandas tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#csv).